# Random changing of values of array of structs

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

Within my code i am reading in names and phone numbers of a file and the names corresponding to the phone numbers. The issue i am having within my code is after the for loop in my load function.

This issue is randomly changing all of the values of my struct name to the last assigned name. Also i dont understand fully how to convert from a split token to float from string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct _data {
     char *name;
     long number;
};

int SCAN(FILE *(*stream)){
     int count;
     char dataString[50];
     int check = 1;
     count = 0;

     while(check){
          fscanf(*stream, "%s\n", dataString);
          fscanf(*stream, "%s\n", dataString);
          if (feof(*stream)){
               check = 0;
          }
          count++;
     }      
     return count;
}

struct _data *LOAD(FILE *stream, int size){
     int x;
     char *tempLine;
     size_t length = 0;
     const char delim[2] = " ";
     char *token;

     rewind(stream);
     struct _data *array = malloc(sizeof(struct _data) * size);  
     printf("this is the size: %d\n\n", size);
     for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
          getline(&tempLine, &length, stream);
          token = strtok(tempLine, delim);
          //printf("this is inside the for loop of load: %s\n", token);
          array[x].name = token;
          token = strtok(tempLine, delim);
          //printf("this is the token: %s\n", token);
          array[x].number = atol(token);
          printf("this is name %s, and phone number %ld\n", array[x].name, array[x].number);
     }
     printf("i am now outside the initial for loop in load\n\n");
     for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
               printf("this is name %s, and phone number %ld\n", array[x].name, array[x].number);
          }
     return array;

}

void SEARCH(struct _data *BlackBox, char *name, int size){
     int x;
     int check = 0;
     for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
          printf("BlackBox Name: %s, check name: %s\n", BlackBox[x].name, name);
          //printf("this is the check: %d\n", strcmp(BlackBox[x].name, name));
          if (0 == strcmp(BlackBox[x].name, name)){
               printf("*******************************************\n");
               printf("The name was found at the %d entry.\n", x);
               printf("*******************************************\n");
               check = 1;  
          }
     }
     if (check == 0){
          printf("*******************************************\n");
          printf("The name was NOT found.\n");
          printf("*******************************************\n");
     }
}

void FREE(struct _data *BlackBox, int size){
     free(BlackBox);
}

int  main(int argv, char **argc){
     FILE *fp;
     int size;
     int x;
     struct _data *BlackBox;
     if(argv < 2){
          printf("*******************************************\n");
          printf("* You must include a name to search for.  *\n");
          printf("*******************************************\n");
     }else{
          fp = fopen("hw5.data", "r");
          size = SCAN(&fp);
          BlackBox = LOAD(fp, size);
         /* for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
               printf("BlackBox Name: %s, check name: %s\n", BlackBox[x].name, argc[1]);
          }*/          
          SEARCH(BlackBox, argc[1], size);
          FREE(BlackBox, size);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Here is my input

```
ron 7774013
jon 7774014
tom 7774015
won 7774016
bonny 7774017
```

Here is my output

```
ron 0
jon 0 
tom 0 
won 0 
bonny 0
i am now outside the initial for loop in load
bonny 0
bonny 0
bonny 0
bonny 0
bonny 0
```

Comment: `array[x].name = token;` only copies the pointer of a place in `tempLine`, Likely you want a copy of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep reusing the space allocated by `getline()` — so you only see the last values.  You need to set `tempLine` to NULL and `length` to 0 after the loop.  You should also be checking the return value from `getline()` to ensure you actually got data to read.

Your second call to `strtok()` should use a NULL pointer.  By respecifying `tempLine`, you are converting the name to a number.

```
      getline(&tempLine, &length, stream);
      token = strtok(tempLine, delim);
      //printf("this is inside the for loop of load: %s\n", token);
      array[x].name = token;
      token = strtok(tempLine, delim);
                     ^^^ should be NULL!
```

You should have spotted this problem when you printed the token.

This code might work as desired — it hasn't been compiled, though.

```
struct _data *LOAD(FILE *stream, int size)
{
    char *tempLine = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;
    const char delim[] = " ";
    char *token;
    int x;

    rewind(stream);
    struct _data *array = malloc(sizeof(struct _data) * size);
    printf("this is the size: %d\n\n", size);
    for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        if (getline(&tempLine, &length, stream) == -1)
        {
            free(tempLine);
            break;
        }
        token = strtok(tempLine, delim);
        // printf("this is inside the for loop of load: [%s]\n", token);
        array[x].name = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        // printf("this is the token: [%s]\n", token);
        array[x].number = atol(token);
        printf("%d: this is name %s, and phone number %ld\n", x, array[x].name, array[x].number);
        length = 0;
        tempLine = NULL;
    }
    printf("i am now outside the initial for loop in load\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: this is name %s, and phone number %ld\n", i, array[i].name, array[i].number);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Also note that you should generally steer clear of creating names that start with an underscore (such as `struct _data`).  Many such names are reserved for use by the implementation; it is simplest to avoid creating names that start with an underscore altogether.

Comment: Yes!!! that worked, thank you!! But yeah, this I am using predefined functions from my professor, so this is why i had the names that way (that was how he had them defined in the homework assignment)

Comment: You can't help professors who have bad coding habits.  Note the problem, ask about it if you're brave, and remember for your own work.

Comment: so, the issue was because i was having the name on each of the indexes set to a pointer. Because of this it was getting redirected to the address of the pointer which in turn had the last value, am i correct in this assumption?

Comment: Yes — that's basically correct.  If you'd had a really long line, you might have managed to make `getline()` allocate a longer buffer, in which case you might have had two sets of values in your array, but the threshold is often 256 for the initial allocation so the line would have been quite long indeed.  By resetting the length and pointer to NULL on each iteration, you force `getline()` to allocate on each call.  The allocation is done before EOF is detected, so the EOF detection needs to free the allocated space.

Comment: Sweet, thank you. you really helped me learn actually, definitely one of the better people with answers i have seen.

Comment: Note that there's a nasty problem lurking in the wings if you get around to freeing memory.  Suppose the user precedes the input with 2 blanks; then the pointer saved in `array[x].name` won't be the pointer returned by `malloc()`, so trying to free it will wreak havoc.  Either don't free the memory, or ensure there's no leading blanks, or keep a record of the pointer returned by `malloc()` as well as the name found by `strtok()`.